# Way to retrieve previous installed version in SPEC file

Tags: centos7, yum, rpm-spec

maybe this is a dumb question but I searched and didn't found anything. Is there any elegant way inside a SPEC definition file to retrieve the previous installed version on the local machine of the same package defined in the SPEC using maybe some variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but your `%pre` scriptlet will be called with `2` as the first parameter if it is an upgrade. You can then do anything you want with that information, like parse the existing `README` or even run `/path/to/your/tool --version` and parse it. Or maybe you have a hidden file `/path/to/your/tool/.version` to make your script even simpler.

More info about scriptlets [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/).

Comment: Thank you for the response. `/path/to/your/tool --version` is indeed a simple and great idea... At the end I have done that by saving in a macro the result of the command `rpm -qi --queryString "%VERSION%" PACKAGE_NAME`

Comment: However, in my opinion, it seems a little absurd not to have this feature integrated...

Comment: Please elaborate your comment "saving in a macro" - do you mean an environmental variable from within the script? If you mean an RPM macro, then it might be happening at **build time**. Check the final scripts in the RPM! Calling the `rpm` executable from scriptlets is a _really_ bad idea and _might_ be working because it's only a read operation. That's why I _intentionally_ didn't mention `rpm -qi` in my answer.

Comment: I have done something like this: `%global _prevver $(rpm -qa --queryformat '%{VERSION}' eplate-rest)` in the %pre phase. If it is not safe to call rpm here I can save that value from the `path/to/tool --version`

Comment: Then that is getting the version of the RPM installed **on the build machine at build time** and not the target machine at install time. You need to do it another way. You can verify this by looking at the scripts - `rpm -qp --scripts your_rpm.rpm`

Comment: Thank you, in the end I have retrieved the version by using my software (using node) and saved in a temporary file..